# Email wildcard subdomain using Exim

Tags: email, exim, wildcard

I want to process all emails sent to *@*.example.com (that is any 
subdomain of example.com) to a PHP script using EXIM. Is this possible and can someone show me a tutorial/clue related to this one.

I'm creating a SaaS apps that create subdomain.example.com to a user with and email *@subdomain.example.com with it.

I've already setup the wildcard dns for domain and mx 
*.example.com.   14400   IN      A       202.190.178.56
mail             14400   IN      A       202.190.178.56
*.example.com.   14400   IN      MX      10 mail

I hope can receive some example or clue to the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

There are some addresses you should exempt such as postmaster, abuse, hostmaster, and any other administrative addresses.  I would recommend you pick a domain or two that will be used for email rather than wildcarding the domain.

- Configure local_domains to include *.example.com, or a specific list of domains.
- Enable wildcard aliases and configure an wildcard alias to and local part which will run your process.  Add a router to handle this id and direct it to a new transport.   Add the new transport to run your program.
- Test and release

You will likely need to configure the transport to run as a specific user.